# Is being naked good for you?

Tags: social-psychology, sexuality

What are the psychological effects and correlates of **social nudism**?

*No opinions, only research, please.*

Comment: I feel like this question, as it stands, lacks any theoretic motivation. There are an infinite number of questions we could ask about the human mind, but only a small finite amount of resources. If you could broaden the context of *why* you are interested in this question, then perhaps some relevant research literature could be found to answer it, even if they only use related constructs (e.g. work on activism or modesty or fashion depending on your motivation for asking).

Comment: This, like everything else, depends solely upon the good derived from it as an individual. Oh, and "yes."

Comment: it's pretty easy to answer, no research paper needed, if you're shy, it makes you feel weak and more shy, if you're not shy, it feels like challenging the world "I'm free i do what I want" that's all

Comment: This question is about a non norm social behaviour and does not reflect sufficient amount of research to warrant an answer.

Comment: @StevenJeuris: I don't see why this was closed. Initial research is not required, though it bears on voting. I upvoted anyway because I find the question interesting and potentially useful – I could edit in motivating arguments as per zergylord's suggestion myself if it were my question (of course, I could regardless, if you like). Unusual social behavior is directly on-topic...and frankly, I suspect caseyr547's flag was vindictive (cf. [e.g.](http://meta.cogsci.stackexchange.com/q/834/4086)).